# Robin Herbots jquery.inputmask allow many values comma separated

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

I have this setup and it works nice:

```
$('#PhoneNumber').inputmask({ mask: "89999999999", placeholder: "" });
```

It allows typing phone numbers starting with "8". But now I would like it to accept many such phone numbers delimited by a comma.

```
81234567890               -- rorrect
81234567890, 80987654321  -- rorrect
81234567890,80987654321   -- rorrect
81234567890,              -- not correct
81234567890,,             -- not correct
81234567890, 80987654321, -- not correct

             ...and so on...
```

[This is the plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex mode with the expression `^[0-9]{8}([,.][0-9]{8})+$`:

```js
$('#phoneNumbers').inputmask({
  regex: "^[0-9]{8}([,.][0-9]{8})+$",
  placeholder: ""
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<input id="phoneNumbers">
```